# How do you make a recipe for kivy-ios?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, kivy, recipe

I have made an app that uses NumPy, SciPy and Pandas which I want to put onto my iOS device. I compile and build using Kivy-iOS but there are errors with the Pandas and SciPy packages and they can't simply be installed via `pip install` or `python toolchain.py pip install`.

I have been looking around all day at forums etc and it seems these two need to be built into a recipe. There is already a NumPy recipe that I have included in my attempts to compile, but this doesn't include the other packages.

I haven't ever made a recipe before and can't really find any info on how to do it.

Has anyone done a Pandas or Scipy recipe before, or even some other recipe that I could follow?

EDIT:
I am still unable to find any solutions on this, it seems there is little to no info available on the subject. With my build using kivy-iOS, when I run it in XCode I get the error `no module named mmap` which I have seen is supposed to be in the python build. So I am unsure what is happening.

If anyone could please help me out, that would be great as I'm very stuck right now.

EDIT:
Bump

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I prepared something like this, for Mqtt:

```
from kivy_ios.toolchain import PythonRecipe
class PahoMqtt(PythonRecipe):
   version = "1"
   url = "https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"
   depends = ["python"]

   recipe = PahoMqtt()
```

I put it in ..kivy_ios/recipes/paho_mqtt directory. I'm not sure but after 'toolchain build paho_mqtt', compilation process appears to be fine. It works!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. How could I get this to work with mmap for example?

Comment: I think, the similar way. If I could I would help You. But I'm not expert with Python/kivy/iOS_programming, just beginner. Try to write Your own recipe as above (change names, package source, etc). As I remember, I had to build freetype==2.10.0 too. Then try to compile. That's all what I can say. General rule is; when your library is pure Python, wont't be a problem to make it workable with Kivy, I think.